# how to put list values to website one by one and put those values to that website textbox area and get output using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a list of values. All I want is, go to that typical website and select values from my list and fill those list values and get output using python.
For example,
mylist=[apple, Samsung, Huawei and list goes on] and let's say the website is Amazon.com and I want to put these list values to amazon page typical text box area and return the output back using python.
I tried web scraping and it seems like to pull the data from the web. Not to push data to the web and get results.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to submit a form on some webpages.  This is usually done by making a HTTP POST request.  Python can do this with the [request framework](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

You can learn how to structure the request from your web inspector.

Another option would be to use a web driver like [selenium](https://selenium.dev/projects/).